# How to get list of data from database to spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

I want to get all username from my user table to be displayed in my spinner for selection but instead of displaying all username from my list it displays only one which is the first user from my database.. how can i get all username?

```
   String q = "SELECT * FROM " + User.TABLE;
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(q, null);
    String[] ComRep = new String[0];
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String rep = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(User.KEY_username));

        do {

            ComRep = new String[]{rep};
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();

    Comrep = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spincomrep);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterrep = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, ComRep);
    adapterrep.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Comrep.setAdapter(adapterrep);
    Comrep.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Comrep.setSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually accumulating any values in your array. You're making a new array each time you go through the loop.

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String rep = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(User.KEY_username));
    values.add(rep);
}
cursor.close();

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterrep = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, values.toArray(new String[values.size]));
```

You should look at `CursorAdapter`.  You could make an adapter directly from your cursor so you don't need to code the loop.

Comment: Now i know..  Thanks for the info..  And thank u so much @bohica